# Simulink sychronized subsystems

Tags: simulink

In simulink, when you clone a subsystem, after a while, you need to update them. The problem is that when you update a subsystem, the cloned one is not updated as well. Is there any way to synchronize the cloned subsystem in a way that when you change each of the subsystems, all original and clones get the influence?

In another word, I need several subsystems with only one identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's what libraries are for. You need to create your own library, then any change that you make to the block in the library will be propagated to all models using that block, provided that the library blocks are not disabled/broken. For more details, see [Create Block Libraries](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-block-libraries.html) in the Simulink documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [Libraries](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/about-block-libraries.html) are for.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't see you already had an answer when I wrote mine, sorry.

Comment: @am304, my answer had been deleted by Hossein Narimani Rad, as per his comment above, at the time you posted your answer.